# SQL result rows from sqlsrv_fetch_array returns zero values

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a SQL query (against a MSSQL database) that looks like this:

```
$sql_timekort = "SELECT
status,
timematrise.ansatt,
SUM(normaltimer) AS normaltimer,
SUM(overtid_1) AS overtid_1,
SUM(overtid_2) AS overtid_2,
SUM(kilometer) AS kilometer,
COUNT(diett) AS diett,
COUNT(CASE WHEN diett = 'ja' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS diett

FROM timematrise

WHERE status = '6'
AND dato LIKE '2019-02%'

GROUP BY ansatt, status";
```

Which is run by sqlsrv in PHP like this:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($timeregistrering_tilkobling, $sql_timekort); if( $stmt === false) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) ); }
```

Result of this query looks like this in SQL Management Studio:

[image]

This result is as expected, and the SQL query seems to work ok. But when I do an sqlsrv_fetch_array like this:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

This is the result:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 6
    [ansatt] => 270
    [normaltimer] => .00
    [overtid_1] => .00
    [overtid_2] => .00
    [kilometer] => 0
    [diett] => 0
)
```

And this is where I am confused. **Where are the numbers**? Every number is either .00 or 0.

The table is defined like this:

```
status: int
ansatt: int
normaltimer: decimal(18, 2)
overtid_1: decimal(18, 2)
overtid_2: decimal(18, 2)
kilometer: decimal(18, 0)
diett: varchar(50)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/formatting-decimals-sqlsrv-driver?view=sqlallproducts-allversions . This may depend on your PHP version or SQL Server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your error, because in Windows environment (PHP Driver for SQL Server 4.0.3, SQL Server 2012) all values from `decimal` columns are returned correctly. But this is [reported issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/415) in Linux. Reported problems are: 1) The money fields returns 4 digits after point and 2) The decimal fields don't returns 0 at the start.

From version 5.6 of of PHP Driver for SQL Server you can use [FormatDecimals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/formatting-decimals-sqlsrv-driver?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) option at connection and statement levels for both drivers for formatting decimal values in the fetched results. So, this will be the obvious solution.

Comment: This actually works! With the FormatDecimals option at the connection every result is working. Thank you!